# How to handle/show errors/exceptions when using concurrent.futures

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

When using the new concurrent.futures library in python with multiprocessing/multithreading. How can i expose errors so that they are displayed.

I have deliberately introduced an error into the `get_user_object` with a variable that doesn't exist. I would expect an error to been thrown at me here but instead the program hangs/complete immediatly.

```py
import concurrent.futures
import multiprocessing as mp


def get_user_object(batch, doesent_exist):

    with _COUNTER.get_lock():
        _COUNTER.value += 1
        print(_COUNTER.value, end=' ')

    #error here
     print(variable_that_doesent_exist)


def init_globals(counter):
    global _COUNTER
    _COUNTER = counter


def main():
    counter = mp.Value('i', 0)
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(
        initializer=init_globals, initargs=(counter,)
    ) as executor:
        for _ in executor.map(get_user_object, range(10)):
            pass
    print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```